# NTFS formatted hard disk's partitions not visible in Windows. Although they are visible in Linux

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, 14.04, ntfs

I have two hard disks. HD1 has two partitions - a NTFS partitions with windows 8.1 and an ext3 with Ubuntu 14.04. HD2 has 4 NTFS partitions. Both of the disks (all partitions) are visible on Ubuntu 14.04. And all NTFS partitions used to be visible/accessible on Windows. But yesterday after upgradeding to Ubuntu 14.04 from 13.10 I am unable to see any HD2 NTFS partitions on windows.

In Device manager panel in windows, on clicking 'scan for H/w changes' it shows the name of my HD2, but partitions still don't show up in File Explorer.

Comment: Seems like a windows problem to me?! You should ask that here http://superuser.com/ probably

Comment: It could be that your partition type codes have changed. Examine them with `gdisk` (or `fdisk` if the affected disk uses MBR). For Windows to see them, they should have a type code of 0700 in `gdisk` (or 07 in `fdisk` on MBR disks). If the Windows partitions have some other type code, like 8300 (or 83 in `fdisk`), then you need to change them.